# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a (26424 x 144) array and I want to perform PCA over it using Python. However, there is no particular place on the web that explains about how to achieve this task (There are some sites which just do PCA according to their own - there is no generalized way of doing so that I can find). Anybody with any sort of help will do great.

Comment: is your array sparse (mostly 0) ? Do you care how much of the variance the top 2-3 components capture -- 50 %, 90 % ?

Comment: No its not sparse, I have it filtered for erroneous values. Yes, I am interested in finding about how many principal components are needed to explain > 75% and >90% of the variance...but not sure how. Any ideas on this?

Comment: look at the sorted `evals` from eigh in Doug's answer -- post the top few and the sum if you like, here or a new question. And see wikipedia [PCA cumulative energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Compute_the_cumulative_energy_content_for_each_eigenvector)

Comment: A comparison of basic PCA approaches, using only `numpy` and/or `scipy`, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68122581), with `timeit` results.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can find a PCA function in the matplotlib module:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA

data = np.array(np.random.randint(10,size=(10,3)))
results = PCA(data)
```

results will store the various parameters of the PCA.
It is from the mlab part of matplotlib, which is the compatibility layer with the MATLAB syntax

EDIT:
on the blog [nextgenetics](http://blog.nextgenetics.net/?e=42) I found a wonderful demonstration of how to perform and display a PCA with the matplotlib mlab module, have fun and check that blog!

Comment: Enrico, thanks. I am using this 3D scenario to 3D PCA plots. Thanks again. I will get in touch if some problem occurs.

Comment: @khan the function PCA from matplot.mlab is deprecated. (http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html?highlight=mlab#deprecated-functions). In addition, it uses SVD, which given the size of the OPs data matrix will be an expensive computation. Using a covariance matrix (see my answer below) you can reduce the size of the matrix in the eigenvector computation by more than 100X.

Comment: I have no doubt that your code may be faster, but for a quick and dirt PCA an already prepared and tested solution can be better. DRY. By the way, it doesn't seem to be deprecated. the deprecated function is the prepca, but is a different one.

Comment: @doug: it isn't deprecated ... they just dropped it documentation. I assume.

Comment: I'm sad, because these three lines of code do not work!

Comment: I think you want to add and change the following commands @user2988577: `import numpy as np` and `data = np.array(np.random.randint(10,size=(10,3)))`. Then I would suggest following this tutorial to help you see how to plot http://blog.nextgenetics.net/?e=42

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'PCA' from 'matplotlib.mlab'. What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 101):

I posted my answer even though another answer has already been accepted; the accepted answer relies on a [deprecated function](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html?highlight=mlab#deprecated-functions); additionally, this deprecated function is based on *Singular Value Decomposition* (SVD), which (although perfectly valid) is the much more memory- and processor-intensive of the two general techniques for calculating PCA. This is particularly relevant here because of the size of the data array in the OP. Using covariance-based PCA, the array used in the computation flow is just *144 x 144*, rather than *26424 x 144* (the dimensions of the original data array).

Here's a simple working implementation of PCA using the ***linalg*** module from *SciPy*. Because this implementation first calculates the covariance matrix, and then performs all subsequent calculations on this array, it uses far less memory than SVD-based PCA.

(the linalg module in *NumPy* can also be used with no change in the code below aside from the import statement, which would be *from numpy import linalg as LA*.)

The two key steps in this PCA implementation are:

- calculating the ***covariance matrix***; and
- taking the ***eivenvectors*** & ***eigenvalues*** of this *cov* matrix

In the function below, the parameter **dims_rescaled_data** refers to the desired number of dimensions in the *rescaled* data matrix; this parameter has a default value of just two dimensions, but the code below isn't limited to two but it could be *any* value less than the column number of the original data array.

---

```
def PCA(data, dims_rescaled_data=2):
    """
    returns: data transformed in 2 dims/columns + regenerated original data
    pass in: data as 2D NumPy array
    """
    import numpy as NP
    from scipy import linalg as LA
    m, n = data.shape
    # mean center the data
    data -= data.mean(axis=0)
    # calculate the covariance matrix
    R = NP.cov(data, rowvar=False)
    # calculate eigenvectors & eigenvalues of the covariance matrix
    # use 'eigh' rather than 'eig' since R is symmetric, 
    # the performance gain is substantial
    evals, evecs = LA.eigh(R)
    # sort eigenvalue in decreasing order
    idx = NP.argsort(evals)[::-1]
    evecs = evecs[:,idx]
    # sort eigenvectors according to same index
    evals = evals[idx]
    # select the first n eigenvectors (n is desired dimension
    # of rescaled data array, or dims_rescaled_data)
    evecs = evecs[:, :dims_rescaled_data]
    # carry out the transformation on the data using eigenvectors
    # and return the re-scaled data, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors
    return NP.dot(evecs.T, data.T).T, evals, evecs

def test_PCA(data, dims_rescaled_data=2):
    '''
    test by attempting to recover original data array from
    the eigenvectors of its covariance matrix & comparing that
    'recovered' array with the original data
    '''
    _ , _ , eigenvectors = PCA(data, dim_rescaled_data=2)
    data_recovered = NP.dot(eigenvectors, m).T
    data_recovered += data_recovered.mean(axis=0)
    assert NP.allclose(data, data_recovered)
    

def plot_pca(data):
    from matplotlib import pyplot as MPL
    clr1 =  '#2026B2'
    fig = MPL.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    data_resc, data_orig = PCA(data)
    ax1.plot(data_resc[:, 0], data_resc[:, 1], '.', mfc=clr1, mec=clr1)
    MPL.show()

>>> # iris, probably the most widely used reference data set in ML
>>> df = "~/iris.csv"
>>> data = NP.loadtxt(df, delimiter=',')
>>> # remove class labels
>>> data = data[:,:-1]
>>> plot_pca(data)
```

The plot below is a visual representation of this PCA function on the iris data. As you can see, a 2D transformation cleanly separates class I from class II and class III (but not class II from class III, which in fact requires another dimension).

[image]

Comment: I agree to your suggestions..seems interesting and honestly, much less memory consuming approach. I have gigs of multidimensional data and I will test these techniques to see which one works the best. Thanks :-)

Comment: How to retrieve the 1st principal component with this method? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916837/how-to-get-the-1st-principal-component-by-pca-using-python

Comment: Has this been tested?  The provided code does not run.  MPL isn't defined, neither is dim1...

Comment: I think `dim1` should be `data.shape` and that `import matplotlib.pyplot as MPL` should be added.

Comment: @doug-- since your test doesn't run (What's `m`?  Why aren't `eigenvalues, eigenvectors` in the PCA return defined before they are returned? etc), it's kind of hard to use this in any useful way...

Comment: @mmr I've posted a working example based on this answer (in a new answer)

Comment: Just to point out a typo: it should be `return NP.dot(evecs.T, data.T).T, evals, evecs` in `PCA`.

Comment: @Lei Huang nice one! editing in accord with your comment above just now. thanks!

Comment: I think you should also have: evals = evals[:dims_rescaled_data]

Comment: @nmr: the answers to your questions are clear from the code in the pca function; not sure why you don't see them; the code window has a separate right (up & down) scroll bar; probably the first several lines of my pca function is hidden until you scroll all the way up

Comment: Nice function. I added a small modification so that the original passed data wasn't affected by the data (I found that this was happening when using a pandas df). Changed the input argument to `data0` then in first line: `data = data0.copy()`.

Comment: @webelo: appreciated

Comment: Awesome function.Just one doubt,  line `data_resc, data_orig = PCA(data)` in plot_pca() is expecting only two return values, but PCA(data) is returning 3

Comment: @doug `NP.dot(evecs.T, data.T).T`, why not simplify to `np.dot(data, evecs)`?

Comment: This is the explaination I was looking for, Thanks

Comment: @mmr: I suppose the line `m, n = data.shape` can be removed altogether, and the first lines of `test_PCA()` should be: `m , _ , eigenvectors = PCA(data, dim_rescaled_data=2)` and `data_recovered = NP.dot(eigenvectors, m.T).T`, or `data_recovered = NP.dot(m, eigenvectors.T)`.

Answer (score 31):

Another Python PCA using numpy. The same idea as @doug but that one didn't run.

```
from numpy import array, dot, mean, std, empty, argsort
from numpy.linalg import eigh, solve
from numpy.random import randn
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show

def cov(X):
    """
    Covariance matrix
    note: specifically for mean-centered data
    note: numpy's `cov` uses N-1 as normalization
    """
    return dot(X.T, X) / X.shape[0]
    # N = data.shape[1]
    # C = empty((N, N))
    # for j in range(N):
    #   C[j, j] = mean(data[:, j] * data[:, j])
    #   for k in range(j + 1, N):
    #       C[j, k] = C[k, j] = mean(data[:, j] * data[:, k])
    # return C

def pca(data, pc_count = None):
    """
    Principal component analysis using eigenvalues
    note: this mean-centers and auto-scales the data (in-place)
    """
    data -= mean(data, 0)
    data /= std(data, 0)
    C = cov(data)
    E, V = eigh(C)
    key = argsort(E)[::-1][:pc_count]
    E, V = E[key], V[:, key]
    U = dot(data, V)  # used to be dot(V.T, data.T).T
    return U, E, V

""" test data """
data = array([randn(8) for k in range(150)])
data[:50, 2:4] += 5
data[50:, 2:5] += 5

""" visualize """
trans = pca(data, 3)[0]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = subplots(1, 2)
ax1.scatter(data[:50, 0], data[:50, 1], c = 'r')
ax1.scatter(data[50:, 0], data[50:, 1], c = 'b')
ax2.scatter(trans[:50, 0], trans[:50, 1], c = 'r')
ax2.scatter(trans[50:, 0], trans[50:, 1], c = 'b')
show()
```

Which yields the same thing as the much shorter

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

def pca2(data, pc_count = None):
    return PCA(n_components = 4).fit_transform(data)
```

As I understand it, using eigenvalues (first way) is better for high-dimensional data and fewer samples, whereas using Singular value decomposition is better if you have more samples than dimensions.

Comment: Using loops defeats the purpose of numpy. You can achieve the covariance matrix much faster by simply doing matrix multiplication C = data.dot(data.T)

Comment: Hmm or use `numpy.cov` I guess. Not sure why I included my own version.

Comment: The result of your data test and visualize seems randomlly. Can you explain the details how to visualize the data? Like how `scatter(data[50:, 0], data[50:, 1]` make sense?

Comment: @PeterZhu I'm not sure I understand your question. PCA transforms your data to new vectors that maximize variance. The `scatter` command shows the first two rows plotted against each other. So the projection of the data on on all other dimensions to make it 2D.

Comment: @downvoter: if there's some problem with the answer, please leave a comment, so people know what not to do

Comment: @Mark `dot(V.T, data.T).T` Why do you do this dancing, it should be equivalent to `dot(data, V)`? _Edit:_ Ah I see you probably just copied it from above. I added a comment in dough's answer.

Comment: @Ela782 Ow that's true yeah, much easier

Comment: `U = dot(data, V)` does not work as `data.shape = (150,8)` and `V.shape = (2,2)` with `pc_count = 3`

Answer (score 15):

This is a job for `numpy`.

And here's a tutorial demonstrating how pincipal component analysis can be done using `numpy`'s built-in modules like `mean,cov,double,cumsum,dot,linalg,array,rank`.

http://glowingpython.blogspot.sg/2011/07/principal-component-analysis-with-numpy.html

Notice that `scipy` also has a long explanation here 
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/babe4a5d0637ca172d47e1dfdd2f6f3c3ecb28db/scikits/learn/utils/extmath.py#L105

with the `scikit-learn` library having more code examples -
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/babe4a5d0637ca172d47e1dfdd2f6f3c3ecb28db/scikits/learn/utils/extmath.py#L105

Comment: I think the linked glowingpython blogpost has a number of mistakes in the code, be wary. (see the latest comments on the blog)

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri Agree with you +$\infty$

Comment: Sorry, I was sarcastic. That glowing python doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

Here are scikit-learn options. With both methods, StandardScaler was used because [PCA is effected by scale](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_scaling_importance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-scaling-importance-py)

Method 1: Have scikit-learn choose the **minimum** number of principal components such that at least x% (90% in example below) of the variance is retained.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

iris = load_iris()

# mean-centers and auto-scales the data
standardizedData = StandardScaler().fit_transform(iris.data)

pca = PCA(.90)

principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X = standardizedData)

# To get how many principal components was chosen
print(pca.n_components_)
```

Method 2: Choose the number of principal components (in this case, 2 was chosen)

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

iris = load_iris()

standardizedData = StandardScaler().fit_transform(iris.data)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)

principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X = standardizedData)

# to get how much variance was retained
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.sum())
```

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** `matplotlib.mlab.PCA` is since release 2.2 (2018-03-06) indeed [deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.PCA).

<del>The library `matplotlib.mlab.PCA` (used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13224566/2771733)) is **not** deprecated. So for all the folks arriving here via Google, I'll post a complete working example tested with Python 2.7.</del>

Use the following code with care as it uses a now deprecated library!

```
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
import numpy
data = numpy.array( [[3,2,5], [-2,1,6], [-1,0,4], [4,3,4], [10,-5,-6]] )
pca = PCA(data)
```

Now in `pca.Y' is the original data matrix in terms of the principal components basis vectors. More details about the PCA object can be found [here](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/pca/pca_docs.shtml).

```
>>> pca.Y
array([[ 0.67629162, -0.49384752,  0.14489202],
   [ 1.26314784,  0.60164795,  0.02858026],
   [ 0.64937611,  0.69057287, -0.06833576],
   [ 0.60697227, -0.90088738, -0.11194732],
   [-3.19578784,  0.10251408,  0.00681079]])
```

You can use `matplotlib.pyplot` to draw this data, just to convince yourself that the PCA yields "good" results. The `names` list is just used to annotate our five vectors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
names = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ]
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(pca.Y[:,0], pca.Y[:,1])
for label, x, y in zip(names, pca.Y[:,0], pca.Y[:,1]):
    matplotlib.pyplot.annotate( label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(-2, 2), textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom' )
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Looking at our original vectors we'll see that data[0] ("A") and data[3] ("D") are rather similar as are data[1] ("B") and data[2] ("C"). This is reflected in the 2D plot of our PCA transformed data.

[image: PCA result plot]

Answer (score 4):

### In addition to all the other answers, here is some code to plot the `biplot` using `sklearn` and `matplotlib`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
#In general a good idea is to scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X=scaler.transform(X)    

pca = PCA()
x_new = pca.fit_transform(X)

def myplot(score,coeff,labels=None):
    xs = score[:,0]
    ys = score[:,1]
    n = coeff.shape[0]
    scalex = 1.0/(xs.max() - xs.min())
    scaley = 1.0/(ys.max() - ys.min())
    plt.scatter(xs * scalex,ys * scaley, c = y)
    for i in range(n):
        plt.arrow(0, 0, coeff[i,0], coeff[i,1],color = 'r',alpha = 0.5)
        if labels is None:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, "Var"+str(i+1), color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
        else:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, labels[i], color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.xlabel("PC{}".format(1))
plt.ylabel("PC{}".format(2))
plt.grid()

#Call the function. Use only the 2 PCs.
myplot(x_new[:,0:2],np.transpose(pca.components_[0:2, :]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've made a little script for comparing the different PCAs appeared as an answer here:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import svd

shape = (26424, 144)
repeat = 20
pca_components = 2

data = np.array(np.random.randint(255, size=shape)).astype('float64')

# data normalization
# data.dot(data.T)
# (U, s, Va) = svd(data, full_matrices=False)
# data = data / s[0]

from fbpca import diffsnorm
from timeit import default_timer as timer

from scipy.linalg import svd
start = timer()
for i in range(repeat):
    (U, s, Va) = svd(data, full_matrices=False)
time = timer() - start
err = diffsnorm(data, U, s, Va)
print('svd time: %.3fms, error: %E' % (time*1000/repeat, err))


from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
start = timer()
_pca = PCA(data)
for i in range(repeat):
    U = _pca.project(data)
time = timer() - start
err = diffsnorm(data, U, _pca.fracs, _pca.Wt)
print('matplotlib PCA time: %.3fms, error: %E' % (time*1000/repeat, err))

from fbpca import pca
start = timer()
for i in range(repeat):
    (U, s, Va) = pca(data, pca_components, True)
time = timer() - start
err = diffsnorm(data, U, s, Va)
print('facebook pca time: %.3fms, error: %E' % (time*1000/repeat, err))


from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
start = timer()
_pca = PCA(n_components = pca_components)
_pca.fit(data)
for i in range(repeat):
    U = _pca.transform(data)
time = timer() - start
err = diffsnorm(data, U, _pca.explained_variance_, _pca.components_)
print('sklearn PCA time: %.3fms, error: %E' % (time*1000/repeat, err))

start = timer()
for i in range(repeat):
    (U, s, Va) = pca_mark(data, pca_components)
time = timer() - start
err = diffsnorm(data, U, s, Va.T)
print('pca by Mark time: %.3fms, error: %E' % (time*1000/repeat, err))

start = timer()
for i in range(repeat):
    (U, s, Va) = pca_doug(data, pca_components)
time = timer() - start
err = diffsnorm(data, U, s[:pca_components], Va.T)
print('pca by doug time: %.3fms, error: %E' % (time*1000/repeat, err))
```

pca_mark is the [pca in Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933271/3162918).

pca_doug is the [pca in doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13224592/3162918).

Here is an example output (but the result depends very much on the data size and pca_components, so I'd recommend to run your own test with your own data. Also, facebook's pca is optimized for normalized data, so it will be faster and more accurate in that case):

```
svd time: 3212.228ms, error: 1.907320E-10
matplotlib PCA time: 879.210ms, error: 2.478853E+05
facebook pca time: 485.483ms, error: 1.260335E+04
sklearn PCA time: 169.832ms, error: 7.469847E+07
pca by Mark time: 293.758ms, error: 1.713129E+02
pca by doug time: 300.326ms, error: 1.707492E+02
```

**EDIT:**

The [diffsnorm](https://fbpca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=diffsnorms#fbpca.diffsnorm) function from fbpca calculates the spectral-norm error of a Schur decomposition.

Comment: Accuracy is not the same as error as you have called it. Can you please fix this and explain the metric as it is not intuitive why this is considered reputable? Also, it is not fair to compare Facebook's "Random PCA" with the covariance version of PCA. Lastly, have you considered that some libraries standardize the input data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, you are right regarding to the accuracy / error difference, I have modified my answer. I think there is a point comparing random PCA with PCA according to speed and accuracy, since both are for dimensionality reduction. Why do you think I should consider the standardization?

Answer (score 1):

This will may be the simplest answer one can find for the PCA including easily understandable steps. Let say we want to retain 2 principal dimensions from the 144 which provides maximum information.

Firstly, convert your 2-D array to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Here X is your array of size (26424 x 144)
data = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

Then, there are two methods one can go with:

**Method 1: Manual calculation**

Step 1: Apply column standardization on X

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

scalar = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
standardized_data = scalar.fit_transform(data)
```

Step 2: Find Co-variance matrix S of original matrix X

```
sample_data = standardized_data
covar_matrix = np.cov(sample_data)
```

Step 3: Find eigen values and eigen vectors of S (here 2D, so 2 of each)

```
from scipy.linalg import eigh

# eigh() function will provide eigen-values and eigen-vectors for a given matrix.
# eigvals=(low value, high value) takes eigen value numbers in ascending order
values, vectors = eigh(covar_matrix, eigvals=(142,143))

# Converting the eigen vectors into (2,d) shape for easyness of further computations
vectors = vectors.T
```

Step 4: Transform the data

```
# Projecting the original data sample on the plane formed by two principal eigen vectors by vector-vector multiplication.

new_coordinates = np.matmul(vectors, sample_data.T)
print(new_coordinates.T)
```

This `new_coordinates.T` will be of size (26424 x 2) with 2 principal components.

**Method 2: Using Scikit-Learn**

Step 1: Apply column standardization on X

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

scalar = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
standardized_data = scalar.fit_transform(data)
```

Step 2: Initializing the pca

```
from sklearn import decomposition

# n_components = numbers of dimenstions you want to retain
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=2)
```

Step 3: Using pca to fit the data

```
# This line takes care of calculating co-variance matrix, eigen values, eigen vectors and multiplying top 2 eigen vectors with data-matrix X.
pca_data = pca.fit_transform(sample_data)
```

This `pca_data` will be of size (26424 x 2) with 2 principal components.

Comment: Hello Mr. Dipen. I am working on the geometry. My task is to align the geometry such that my principal axes will be parallel or lies on the reference axes (x and y). I do not know the angle at which geometry is rotated.  X coordinate is: [0.0, 0.87, 1.37, 1.87, 2.73, 3.6, 4.46, 4.96, 5.46, 4.6, 3.73, 2.87, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 2.37, 3.23, 4.1]
Y coordinate is: [0.0, 0.5, -0.37, -1.23, -0.73, -0.23, 0.27, -0.6, -1.46, -1.96, -2.46, -2.96, -3.46, -2.6, -1.73, -0.87, -2.1, -1.6, -1.1] These are the coordinates. Would you please let me know if PCA approach will be helpful or not?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake `def plot_pca(data):` will work, it is necessary to replace the lines

```
data_resc, data_orig = PCA(data)
ax1.plot(data_resc[:, 0], data_resc[:, 1], '.', mfc=clr1, mec=clr1)
```

with lines

```
newData, data_resc, data_orig = PCA(data)
ax1.plot(newData[:, 0], newData[:, 1], '.', mfc=clr1, mec=clr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this sample code loads the Japanese yield curve, and creates PCA components.
It then estimates a given date's move using the PCA and compares it against the actual move.

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
from scipy import stats
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

import quandl as ql

start = "2016-10-04"
end = "2019-10-04"

ql_data = ql.get("MOFJ/INTEREST_RATE_JAPAN", start_date = start, end_date = end).sort_index(ascending= False)

eigVal_, eigVec_ = np.linalg.eig(((ql_data[:300]).diff(-1)*100).cov()) # take latest 300 data-rows and normalize to bp
print('number of PCA are', len(eigVal_))

loc_ = 10
plt.plot(eigVec_[:,0], label = 'PCA1')
plt.plot(eigVec_[:,1], label = 'PCA2')
plt.plot(eigVec_[:,2], label = 'PCA3')
plt.xticks(range(len(eigVec_[:,0])), ql_data.columns)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

x = ql_data.diff(-1).iloc[loc_].values * 100 # set the differences
x_ = x[:,np.newaxis]
a1, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(eigVec_[:,0][:, np.newaxis], x_) # linear regression without intercept
a2, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(eigVec_[:,1][:, np.newaxis], x_)
a3, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(eigVec_[:,2][:, np.newaxis], x_)

pca_mv = m1 * eigVec_[:,0] + m2 * eigVec_[:,1] + m3 * eigVec_[:,2] + c1 + c2 + c3
pca_MV = a1[0][0] * eigVec_[:,0] + a2[0][0] * eigVec_[:,1] + a3[0][0] * eigVec_[:,2]
pca_mV = b1 * eigVec_[:,0] + b2 * eigVec_[:,1] + b3 * eigVec_[:,2]

display(pd.DataFrame([eigVec_[:,0], eigVec_[:,1], eigVec_[:,2], x, pca_MV]))
print('PCA1 regression is', a1, a2, a3)


plt.plot(pca_MV)
plt.title('this is with regression and no intercept')
plt.plot(ql_data.diff(-1).iloc[loc_].values * 100, )
plt.title('this is with actual moves')
plt.show()
```