# Transpose in SPSS

Tags: python, scripting, spss

I have 525 rows/records for 35 columns of data in an SPSS project. My goal is to run a q-mode PCA which is a PCA that is run on a transposed table.

Are there any Python scripts for SPSS or other tips for automating this process?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224362/pca-analysis-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding 'natural' groups of cases (rather than variables) in data, Cluster analysis is more common. However, I'll refrain from discussing the theoretical (un)soundness of both methods. For transposing data please try and run

```
flip.
```

in a syntax window.