# Basic example for PCA with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca

I trying to do a simple principal component analysis with `matplotlib.mlab.PCA` but with the attributes of the class I can't get a clean solution to my problem. Here's an example:

Get some dummy data in 2D and start PCA:

```
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
import numpy as np

N     = 1000
xTrue = np.linspace(0,1000,N)
yTrue = 3*xTrue

xData = xTrue + np.random.normal(0, 100, N)
yData = yTrue + np.random.normal(0, 100, N)
xData = np.reshape(xData, (N, 1))
yData = np.reshape(yData, (N, 1))
data  = np.hstack((xData, yData))
test2PCA = PCA(data)
```

Now, I just want to get the principal components as vectors in my original coordinates and plot them as arrows onto my data.

What is a quick and clean way to get there?

Thanks, Tyrax

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't think the `mlab.PCA` class is appropriate for what you want to do. In particular, the `PCA` class rescales the data before finding the eigenvectors:

```
a = self.center(a)
U, s, Vh = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False)
```

The `center` method divides by `sigma`:

```
def center(self, x):
    'center the data using the mean and sigma from training set a'
    return (x - self.mu)/self.sigma
```

This results in eigenvectors, `pca.Wt`, like this:

```
[[-0.70710678 -0.70710678]
 [-0.70710678  0.70710678]]
```

They are perpendicular, but not directly relevant to the principal axes of your original data. They are principal axes with respect to massaged data.

Perhaps it might be easier to code what you want directly (without the use of the `mlab.PCA` class):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000
xTrue = np.linspace(0, 1000, N)
yTrue = 3 * xTrue
xData = xTrue + np.random.normal(0, 100, N)
yData = yTrue + np.random.normal(0, 100, N)
xData = np.reshape(xData, (N, 1))
yData = np.reshape(yData, (N, 1))
data = np.hstack((xData, yData))

mu = data.mean(axis=0)
data = data - mu
# data = (data - mu)/data.std(axis=0)  # Uncommenting this reproduces mlab.PCA results
eigenvectors, eigenvalues, V = np.linalg.svd(data.T, full_matrices=False)
projected_data = np.dot(data, eigenvectors)
sigma = projected_data.std(axis=0).mean()
print(eigenvectors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(xData, yData)
for axis in eigenvectors:
    start, end = mu, mu + sigma * axis
    ax.annotate(
        '', xy=end, xycoords='data',
        xytext=start, textcoords='data',
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', width=2.0))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what the meaning of the 1.618 constant is ? where it comes from ?

Comment: @joaquin: Its approximately the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). You can, of course, choose any constant you like, but it [often looks good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Painting).

Comment: @unutbu: The two vectors are not orthogonal, something must be wrong here.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I was wondering why pca.Wt had those strange values. I'm still surprised that the pca-class is not really usable for such a simple pca task. The documentation at http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.PCA is unusable imho. There's a better one here: https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/pca/pca_docs.shtml but I was still not able to really understand what's going on.

Comment: Is it coincidence that both vectors are of the same length? Because they are also in my plot. The eigenvalues tell how long they should be, right?

Comment: Doesn't `numpy.linalg.svd()` return the "singular values" (`s`) instead of the `eigenvalues`? As explained e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134283): `eigenvalue=s**2/(n-1)` (for the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix). From the [svd docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html?highlight=svd#numpy.linalg.svd): "... the corresponding (possibly non-zero) eigenvalues are given by `s**2`"

Answer (score 3):

Note that `matplotlib.mlab.PCA` was [removed in 3.1](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/api_changes.html#matplotlib-mlab-removals).

Below are three alternative PCA implementations, one based on the last`matplotlib.mlab.PCA` [implementation](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.4/_modules/matplotlib/mlab.html#PCA), one based on [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299834), and one based on [doug's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13224592).

The first two use singular value decomposition (`svd`) to obtain the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the latter uses a covariance matrix (`cov`) approach.

A magnificent explanation of the relation between the `svd` and `cov` approaches is found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134283).

The implementations have been simplified and refactored for easy comparison.

```
def pca_svd(data):
    """ based on matplotlib.mlab.PCA with standardize=False """
    data -= data.mean(axis=0)
    __, singular_values, eigenvectors_transposed = numpy.linalg.svd(
        data, full_matrices=False)
    eigenvalues = singular_values ** 2 / (data.shape[0] - 1)
    eigenvectors = eigenvectors_transposed.T
    transformed_data = numpy.dot(data, eigenvectors)
    return transformed_data, eigenvalues, eigenvectors


def pca_svd_transposed(data):
    """ based on unutbu's answer """
    data -= data.mean(axis=0)
    eigenvectors, singular_values, __ = numpy.linalg.svd(
        data.T, full_matrices=False)  # note data transposed
    eigenvalues = singular_values ** 2 / (data.shape[0] - 1)
    transformed_data = numpy.dot(data, eigenvectors)
    return transformed_data, eigenvalues, eigenvectors
    
    
def pca_cov(data):
    """ based on doug's answer """
    data -= data.mean(axis=0)
    covariance_matrix = numpy.cov(data, rowvar=False)
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = scipy.linalg.eigh(covariance_matrix)
    decreasing_order = numpy.argsort(eigenvalues)[::-1]
    eigenvalues = eigenvalues[decreasing_order]
    eigenvectors = eigenvectors[:, decreasing_order]
    transformed_data = numpy.dot(data, eigenvectors)
    return transformed_data, eigenvalues, eigenvectors
```

The `eigenvalues` represent the variance of the data along the principal axes, i.e. the variance of the `transformed_data`.

Timing using `timeit` reveals the following on my system:

```
array shape:  (15000, 4)
iterations:  1000
pca_svd_transposed: 4.32 s (average 4.32 ms)
pca_svd:            1.87 s (average 1.87 ms)
pca_cov:            1.41 s (average 1.41 ms)
```

Note that the `svd` of the transposed input array is relatively slow for this array shape.