# How to visualize the first and second components (axis) of 2D PCA?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I'm using sklearn to visualize some n-dimensional data into 2D. Now I want to visualize the principal components (vectors) that show the main axis of variation in the data as in [image: the two axis in the image]. Does anybody know how to do that?
What I need is the slope of those two lines and their direction.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)
#now what are the two slopes?
```

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299523/basic-example-for-pca-with-matplotlib

Comment: @Nickil: Thanks, solved the problem.