# Draw a line through data points and calculate an angle between that line and x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have plotted the x-axis and y-axis on the data points.

Now there are 2 tasks.

1. Draw a diagonal line passing roughly through the middle of data
   points(Consider the black line in the picture below).
2. Calculate the angle between the horizontal blue line and the line
   we draw in task 1.

Note - I have generated the following figure through matplotlib. You can suggest a solution through matplotlib or any other library.

Thanks in advance..

[image]

Comment: For 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299523/basic-example-for-pca-with-matplotlib

Comment: For 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260962/calculating-angles-between-line-segments-python-with-math-atan2

Answer (score 0):

(1) There is plentiful literature on how to compute the line of best fit through an array of n-dimensional points using a sequence of [matrix transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Least-squares_estimation_and_related_techniques) (I recommend NumPy for this).

(2) This is a straightforward mathematical translation: if the slope of your line is `m = (rise) / (run)`, then we have a right triangle under the line. Because `tan(x) = (opp) / (hyp) = (rise) / (run)`, then the angle can be found with `arctan((rise) / (run)) = arctan(m)`, where `m` is the slope of your line.