# How to use Robust PCA output as principal-component (eigen)vectors from traditional PCA

Tags: python, pca

I am using PCA to reduce the dimensionality of a N-dimensional dataset, but I want to build in robustness to large outliers, so I've been looking into Robust PCA codes.

For traditional PCA, I'm using python's sklearn.decomposition.PCA which nicely returns the principal components as vectors, onto which I can then project my data (to be clear, I've also coded my own versions using SVD so I know how the method works). I found a few pre-coded RPCA python codes out there (like https://github.com/dganguli/robust-pca and https://github.com/jkarnows/rpcaADMM).

The 1st code is based on the Candes et al. (2009) method, and returns low rank L and sparse S matrices for a dataset D.  The 2nd code uses the ADMM method of matrix decomposition (Parikh, N., & Boyd, S. 2013) and returns X_1, X_2, X_3 matrices. I must admit, I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to connect these to the principal axes that are returned by a standard PCM algorithm. Can anyone provide any guidance?

Specifically, in one dataset X, I have a cloud of N 3-D points.  I run it through PCA:

```
pca=sklean.decompose.PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(X)
comps=pca.components_
```

and these 3 components are 3-D vectors define the new basis onto which I project all my points. With Robust PCA, I get matrices L+S=X. Does one then run pca.fit(L)?  I would have thought that RPCA would have given me back the eigenvectors but have internal steps to throw out outliers as part of building the covariance matrix or performing SVD.

Maybe what I think of as "Robust PCA" isn't how other people are using/coding it?

Comment: I think it would help if you explained what the problem of connecting those matrices to the vectors of standard PCM algorith is.

Comment: I added to the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 14):

The [`robust-pca` code](https://github.com/dganguli/robust-pca) factors the data matrix `D` into two matrices, `L` and `S` which are "low-rank" and "sparse" matrices (see [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3599.pdf) for details).  `L` is what's mostly constant between the various observations, while `S` is what varies.  Figures 2 and 3 in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3599.pdf) give a really nice example from a couple of security cameras, picking out the static background (`L`) and variability such as passing people (`S`).

If you just want the eigenvectors, treat the `S` as junk (the "large outliers" you're wanting to clip out) and do an eigenanalysis on the `L` matrix.

Here's an example using the [`robust-pca` code](https://github.com/dganguli/robust-pca):

```
    L, S = RPCA(data).fit()
    rcomp, revals, revecs = pca(L)
    print("Normalised robust eigenvalues: %s" % (revals/np.sum(revals),))
```

Here, the `pca` function is:

```
def pca(data, numComponents=None):
    """Principal Components Analysis

    From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13224592/834250

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : `numpy.ndarray`
        numpy array of data to analyse
    numComponents : `int`
        number of principal components to use

    Returns
    -------
    comps : `numpy.ndarray`
        Principal components
    evals : `numpy.ndarray`
        Eigenvalues
    evecs : `numpy.ndarray`
        Eigenvectors
    """
    m, n = data.shape
    data -= data.mean(axis=0)
    R = np.cov(data, rowvar=False)
    # use 'eigh' rather than 'eig' since R is symmetric,
    # the performance gain is substantial
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(R)
    idx = np.argsort(evals)[::-1]
    evecs = evecs[:,idx]
    evals = evals[idx]
    if numComponents is not None:
        evecs = evecs[:, :numComponents]
    # carry out the transformation on the data using eigenvectors
    # and return the re-scaled data, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors
    return np.dot(evecs.T, data.T).T, evals, evecs
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little when this robust pca should be prefered over a regular pca? or is there some handy information or source somewhere?

Comment: @Ben Use robust PCA when you expect that the inputs may have outliers. Have a look at the paper I referenced for an example.

Comment: Would you mind adding the title of the paper? The link is dead.

Comment: It's the paper cited in the `README.md` for the code. I fixed the link.