# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in Python not working

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I am a newbie in Python,  and following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13224566/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.mlab import PCA

pcadata = array(1,2,3)
pcaresults = PCA(pcadata)

print(pcaresults)
```

it is giving error: pcadata = array(1,2,3)
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
Background: I am using Python in Pydev Eclipse in Windows Environment

Comment: read the comments... copied from the link...  "I think you want to add and change the following commands @user2988577: import numpy as np and data = np.array(np.random.randint(10,size=(10,3))). Then I would suggest following this tutorial to help you see how to plot blog.nextgenetics.net/?e=42"

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not implemented in python itself, but in the module `numpy`. Use `np.array([1,2,3])` to generate a one dimensional array containing the integers [1,2,3].

In order to do a principal component analysis, you must have more vectors than degrees of freedom (ie - you must have more rows than columns). Thus you should set `pcadata` to have at least three rows.

```
 `pcadata = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]])`
```

You asked in the comments below, how do I access `pcaresults` values? You can access the normalized centered version of the input with `print(pcaresults.a)`. If you want some of the other attributes of `pcaresults`, you should try `help(pcaresults)` to see what else is contained in `pcaresults`.

Comment: thanks @mark but now error is : pcadata = np.array(1,2,3) 
ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted

Comment: Np @ Jack. If you look at the solution above, there are a set of square brackets around 1,2,3. Square brackets in python denote a list. Why do you need to give np.array a list? numpy's function array takes a single, list-like argument and turns it into an array. Currently, you are giving it three arguments each of which is not list-like.

Comment: oh my bad @Mark, thanks, for the correction
I got it 
also rows must be greater than columns

when i am printing result
     print(type(pcaresults))
     print(pcaresults)
it says 
     <class 'matplotlib.mlab.PCA'>
    <matplotlib.mlab.PCA object at 0x01BDD770>

how can i get its values?