# ImportError: cannot import name 'PCA' from 'matplotlib.mlab'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pca

According to this task:

[Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224362/principal-component-analysis-pca-in-python)

I included this line

```
import from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
```

but I get the error message:

> cannot import name 'PCA' from 'matplotlib.mlab'

I'm using Python3.7 and I have no idea how I can use the PCA function from matlab. Is the new version of matplotlib depricated or is PCA included to another library?

Comment: See the comments and answers you linked. This is discussed there.

Answer (score 6):

I really don't know if it is too late to reply now. But I will just place it here anyways.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
```