# Implementation of Principal Component Analysis from Scratch Orients the Data Differently than scikit-learn

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

Based on the guide [Implementing PCA in Python, by Sebastian Raschka](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html) I am building the PCA algorithm from scratch *for my research purpose*. The class definition is:

```py
import numpy as np

class PCA(object):
    """Dimension Reduction using Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

    It is the procces of computing principal components which explains the
    maximum variation of the dataset using fewer components.

    :type  n_components: int, optional
    :param n_components: Number of components to consider, if not set then
                         `n_components = min(n_samples, n_features)`, where
                         `n_samples` is the number of samples, and
                         `n_features` is the number of features (i.e.,
                         dimension of the dataset).

    Attributes
    ==========
        :type  covariance_: np.ndarray
        :param covariance_: Coviarance Matrix

        :type  eig_vals_: np.ndarray
        :param eig_vals_: Calculated Eigen Values

        :type  eig_vecs_: np.ndarray
        :param eig_vecs_: Calculated Eigen Vectors

        :type  explained_variance_: np.ndarray
        :param explained_variance_: Explained Variance of Each Principal Components

        :type  cum_explained_variance_: np.ndarray
        :param cum_explained_variance_: Cumulative Explained Variables
    """

    def __init__(self, n_components : int = None):
        """Default Constructor for Initialization"""

        self.n_components = n_components

    def fit_transform(self, X : np.ndarray):
        """Fit the PCA algorithm into the Dataset"""

        if not self.n_components:
            self.n_components = min(X.shape)

        self.covariance_ = np.cov(X.T)

        # calculate eigens
        self.eig_vals_, self.eig_vecs_ = np.linalg.eig(self.covariance_)

        # explained variance
        _tot_eig_vals = sum(self.eig_vals_)
        self.explained_variance_ = np.array([(i / _tot_eig_vals) * 100 for i in sorted(self.eig_vals_, reverse = True)])
        self.cum_explained_variance_ = np.cumsum(self.explained_variance_)

        # define `W` as `d x k`-dimension
        self.W_ = self.eig_vecs_[:, :self.n_components]

        print(X.shape, self.W_.shape)
        return X.dot(self.W_)
```

Consider the **iris-dataset** as a test case, PCA is achieved and visualized as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# loading iris data, and normalize
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
X = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X)

# using the PCA function (defined above)
# to fit_transform the X value
# naming the PCA object as dPCA (d = defined)
dPCA = PCA()
principalComponents = dPCA.fit_transform(X)

# creating a pandas dataframe for the principal components
# and visualize the data using scatter plot
PCAResult = pd.DataFrame(principalComponents, columns = [f"PCA-{i}" for i in range(1, dPCA.n_components + 1)])
PCAResult["target"] = y # possible as original order does not change

sns.scatterplot(x = "PCA-1", y = "PCA-2", data = PCAResult, hue = "target", s = 50)
plt.show()
```

The output is as:
[image: PCA-1 vs PCA-2 using Self-Defined PCA Function]

Now, I wanted to **verify the output**, for which I used `sklearn` library, and the output is as follows:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA # note the same name
sPCA = PCA() # consider all the components

principalComponents_ = sPCA.fit_transform(X)
PCAResult_ = pd.DataFrame(principalComponents_, columns = [f"PCA-{i}" for i in range(1, 5)])
PCAResult_["target"] = y # possible as original order does not change

sns.scatterplot(x = "PCA-1", y = "PCA-2", data = PCAResult_, hue = "target", s = 50)
plt.show()
```

[image: PCA-1 vs PCA-2 using sklearn.decompose.PCA]

I don't understand **why the output is oriented differently, with a minor different value**. I studied numerous codes [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13224592/6623589), [2](https://github.com/bhattbhavesh91/pca-from-scratch-iris-dataset/blob/master/Principal_Component_Analysis_Iris_DataSet.ipynb), [3](https://github.com/python-engineer/MLfromscratch/blob/master/mlfromscratch/pca.py)], all of which have the same issue. My questions:

1. What is different in `sklearn`, that the plot is different? I've tried with a different dataset too - the same problem.
2. Is there a way to fix this issue?

I was not able to study the `sklearn.decompose.PCA` algorithm, as I am new to OOPs concept with python.

Output in the blog post by Sebastian Raschka also has a minor variation in output. Figure below:
[image: Output of PCA by Sebastian Raschka]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calculating an eigenvector you may [change its sign](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702730/sign-of-normalized-eigenvector-for-singular-value-decomposition) and the solution will also be a valid one.

So any PCA axis can be reversed and the solution will be valid.

Nevertheless, you may wish to impose a positive correlation of a PCA axis with one of the original variables in the dataset, inverting the axis if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in values comes from PCA from sklearn using svd decomposition. In sklearn there's a function `svd_flip` used to flip the PCs, which explains why you see this flip

More details on the help [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html):

> It uses the LAPACK implementation of the full SVD or a randomized
> truncated SVD by the method of Halko et al. 2009, depending on the
> shape of the input data and the number of components to extract.

You can read about the relation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca)

We first run your example dataset:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.utils.extmath import svd_flip
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy

iris = load_iris()

X, y = iris.data, iris.target
X = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X)

n_components = 4

sPCA = PCA(n_components,svd_solver="full")
sklearnPCs = pd.DataFrame(sPCA.fit_transform(X))
```

We now perform SVD on your centered matrix:

```
U,S,Vt = scipy.linalg.svd(X - X.mean(axis=0))
U = U[:,:n_components]
U, Vt = svd_flip(U, Vt)

svdPCs =  pd.DataFrame(U*S)
```

The results:

```
            0         1         2         3
0   -0.630703  0.107578 -0.018719 -0.007307
1   -0.622905 -0.104260 -0.049142 -0.032359
2   -0.669520 -0.051417  0.019644 -0.007434
3   -0.654153 -0.102885  0.023219  0.020114
4   -0.648788  0.133488  0.015116  0.011786
..        ...       ...       ...       ...
145  0.551462  0.059841  0.086283 -0.110092
146  0.407146 -0.171821 -0.004102 -0.065241
147  0.447143  0.037560  0.049546 -0.032743
148  0.488208  0.149678  0.239209  0.002864
149  0.312066 -0.031130  0.118672  0.052505


svdPCs 
            0         1         2         3
0   -0.630703  0.107578 -0.018719 -0.007307
1   -0.622905 -0.104260 -0.049142 -0.032359
2   -0.669520 -0.051417  0.019644 -0.007434
3   -0.654153 -0.102885  0.023219  0.020114
4   -0.648788  0.133488  0.015116  0.011786
..        ...       ...       ...       ...
145  0.551462  0.059841  0.086283 -0.110092
146  0.407146 -0.171821 -0.004102 -0.065241
147  0.447143  0.037560  0.049546 -0.032743
148  0.488208  0.149678  0.239209  0.002864
149  0.312066 -0.031130  0.118672  0.052505
```

You can implement without the flip. The values will be the same and your PCA will be valid as noted in the other answer.